# Manual for library Libxc

Tags: computational-physics, software

Where can I find the manual for software library Libxc for exchange-correlation functionals? Links with domain [www.tddft.org](http://www.tddft.org) don't work.

Comment: Do you mean [this one](https://gitlab.com/libxc/libxc)? `XC` is not very specific as a library name, one is reminded of the "X window system", and DFT is foremost the discrete Fourier transformation.

Comment: That is the correct one. I recommend the question asker file a bug report via the issues tab in the gitlab site, since the developers will have easy access to the manual.

Comment: I opened an issue in gitlab about this.

Answer (score 1):

So, currently, Libxc project has a home [here](https://libxc.gitlab.io) with [this being its manual](https://libxc.gitlab.io/manual/). Thanks for submitting the [issue](https://gitlab.com/libxc/libxc/issues/125).

Just to point out, if it happens that some content is not present on the [GitLab for Libxc](https://libxc.gitlab.io), you can try to search for it [on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/2018*/http://www.tddft.org/programs/libxc/). It seems like [this project has been saved pretty well, featuring even historic perspective](http://web.archive.org/web/20181009094942/http://www.tddft.org/programs/libxc/manual/).